# damped harmonic oscillator driven by a stochastic momentum (not force)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, physics

Could you give references for solutions or solutions to the following problem:
Given: damped harmonic oscillator driven by stochastic force of very short duration (= stochastic momentum). 
Find: Spectrum of the oscillator; X(w) when the repetition frequency of the driving momentum is > Q-value